# Div to show in centre of page with background stretching across

Tags: css, html, center

Looking at centering  a div across all browser and screen resolutions.
Seen that the left 50% with margin-left of the div width to be quite common but wrapping the div completely in a containing div cuts off the background of my div.

My div will spread across the whole of the screen with a light grey background with an inner div with my content within.

I have tried using percentages and pixels but cannot get it to sit central in both 1920 wide and 1200 wide.

css is as follows:

```
#default-upper-strap {

background-color: #ddd;
width: 109.61%;
margin-top: 25px;
z-index: 99999;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 23px;
margin-left: -8px;
max-width: 1920px;
}

#default-strap-left {
width: 810px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
margin-left: 21%;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using an absolute position with left and right values instead of trying to center using padding and margins? It usually gives quite good results and transparent CSS.

Comment: Which div has the background that is being cut off? Also, why are you specifying a width of 109.61%, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I use a width of 100% it leaves a margin on the right--hand side for some reason. I will try the absolute position and see what I can get from that. Thanks

Comment: What does the parent container for `#default-upper-strap` look like? can you post the HTML? Also, which div is supposed to be centered and which is suppose to be the width of the page? And is #default-strap-left` the child of `#default-upper-strap`?

Comment: <div id="default-upper-strap">
<div id="default-strap-left">
<div class="default-item1">
<h3>Our Promise</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

Comment: <div class="default-item2">
<h3>Confidential Disposal</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

Comment: <div class="default-item3">
<h3>Recycling Credentials</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>

Comment: Why don't you update your original post with your HTML? Use the "edit" link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you start with the following:

```
<div class="default-upper-strap">
    <div class="default-strap-left">Some content...</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.default-upper-strap {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.default-strap-left {
    width: 810px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

Use `margin: 0 auto` to center the child element within the parent container.

When the parent container reaches its maximum width, the `margin: 25px auto 0 auto` rule
will take care of centering the parent container if this is what you want.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JqxY8/

Comment: That works great other than the background is not stretching across the whole of the screen.

I will work with this though and see what I can with the background.

Comment: Which background are you trying to stretch? Remember, you set a max-width value to `.default-upper-strap` and that will limit the background the maximum width.  If you want a background to extent beyond `.default-upper-strap`, then you will need to add a parent wrapper block to `.default-upper-strap` and set that width to 100% and apply the background to the wrapper.

Comment: I have managed to solve the background problem I was having, it was down to my main content not stretching out far enough.